# MongoDB add new field by checking if key value is exists

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a data that look like this

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "22435992",
    "address": "Merr Street",
    "contacted": [
      {
        "_id": "22435992",
        "date": "2022-12-27T04:58:47.306Z",
        "status": "Contacted",
        
      },
      {
        "_id": "22435992",
        "date": "2022-12-27T05:00:50.119Z",
        "status": "Contacted",
        
      },
      {
        "_id": "4f950467",
        "date": "2022-12-27T09:33:51.783Z",
        "status": "Contacted",
        
      },
      {
        "_id": "4f950467",
        "date": "2022-12-27T09:33:55.472Z",
        "status": "Contacted",
        
      },
      {
        "_id": "4f950467",
        "date": "2022-12-27T09:33:58.846Z",
        "status": "Contacted",
        
      },
      
    ],
    "fullName": "Waltz",
    
  },
  {
    "_id": "a2203725",
    "address": "Youm Street",
    "contacted": [
      {
        "_id": "22435992",
        "date": "2022-12-27T04:58:47.306Z",
        "status": "Contacted",
        
      },
      {
        "_id": "22435992",
        "date": "2022-12-27T05:00:50.119Z",
        "status": "Contacted",
        
      },
      {
        "_id": "4f950467",
        "date": "2022-12-27T09:33:51.783Z",
        "status": "Contacted",
        
      },
      {
        "_id": "4f950467",
        "date": "2022-12-27T09:33:55.472Z",
        "status": "Contacted",
        
      },
      {
        "_id": "4f950467",
        "date": "2022-12-27T09:33:58.846Z",
        "status": "Contacted",
        
      },
      
    ],
    "fullName": "Bono",
    
  },
  {
    "_id": "4f950467",
    "address": "Sesame Streetm",
    "contacted": [
      {
        "_id": "22435992",
        "date": "2022-12-27T04:58:47.306Z",
        "status": "Contacted",
        
      },
      {
        "_id": "22435992",
        "date": "2022-12-27T05:00:50.119Z",
        "status": "Contacted",
        
      },
      {
        "_id": "4f950467",
        "date": "2022-12-27T09:33:51.783Z",
        "status": "Contacted",
        
      },
      {
        "_id": "4f950467",
        "date": "2022-12-27T09:33:55.472Z",
        "status": "Contacted",
        
      },
      {
        "_id": "4f950467",
        "date": "2022-12-27T09:33:58.846Z",
        "status": "Contacted",
        
      },
      
    ],
    "fullName": "Axl",
    
  },
  {
    "_id": "3d338340",
    "address": "Reign Street",
    "contacted": [
      {
        "_id": "22435992",
        "date": "2022-12-27T04:58:47.306Z",
        "status": "Contacted",
        
      },
      {
        "_id": "22435992",
        "date": "2022-12-27T05:00:50.119Z",
        "status": "Contacted",
        
      },
      {
        "_id": "4f950467",
        "date": "2022-12-27T09:33:51.783Z",
        "status": "Contacted",
        
      },
      {
        "_id": "4f950467",
        "date": "2022-12-27T09:33:55.472Z",
        "status": "Contacted",
        
      },
      {
        "_id": "4f950467",
        "date": "2022-12-27T09:33:58.846Z",
        "status": "Contacted",
        
      },
      
    ],
    "fullName": "Jean",
    
  },
  
]
```

I want to add a new fields called contactStatus with value that from checking if the userId is exists on contacted array so it will looks like this

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "22435992",
    "address": "Merr Street",
    "contactStatus": "Contacted",
    "contacted": [
      {
        "_id": "22435992",
        "date": "2022-12-27T04:58:47.306Z",
        "status": "Contacted"
      },
      {
        "_id": "22435992",
        "date": "2022-12-27T05:00:50.119Z",
        "status": "Contacted"
      },
      {
        "_id": "4f950467",
        "date": "2022-12-27T09:33:51.783Z",
        "status": "Contacted"
      },
      {
        "_id": "4f950467",
        "date": "2022-12-27T09:33:55.472Z",
        "status": "Contacted"
      },
      {
        "_id": "4f950467",
        "date": "2022-12-27T09:33:58.846Z",
        "status": "Contacted"
      }
    ],
    "fullName": "Waltz"
  },
  {
    "_id": "a2203725",
    "address": "Youm Street",
    "contactStatus": "Not Contacted",
    "contacted": [
      {
        "_id": "22435992",
        "date": "2022-12-27T04:58:47.306Z",
        "status": "Contacted"
      },
      {
        "_id": "22435992",
        "date": "2022-12-27T05:00:50.119Z",
        "status": "Contacted"
      },
      {
        "_id": "4f950467",
        "date": "2022-12-27T09:33:51.783Z",
        "status": "Contacted"
      },
      {
        "_id": "4f950467",
        "date": "2022-12-27T09:33:55.472Z",
        "status": "Contacted"
      },
      {
        "_id": "4f950467",
        "date": "2022-12-27T09:33:58.846Z",
        "status": "Contacted"
      }
    ],
    "fullName": "Bono"
  },
  {
    "_id": "4f950467",
    "address": "Sesame Streetm",
    "contactStatus": "Contacted",
    "contacted": [
      {
        "_id": "22435992",
        "date": "2022-12-27T04:58:47.306Z",
        "status": "Contacted"
      },
      {
        "_id": "22435992",
        "date": "2022-12-27T05:00:50.119Z",
        "status": "Contacted"
      },
      {
        "_id": "4f950467",
        "date": "2022-12-27T09:33:51.783Z",
        "status": "Contacted"
      },
      {
        "_id": "4f950467",
        "date": "2022-12-27T09:33:55.472Z",
        "status": "Contacted"
      },
      {
        "_id": "4f950467",
        "date": "2022-12-27T09:33:58.846Z",
        "status": "Contacted"
      }
    ],
    "fullName": "Axl"
  },
  {
    "_id": "3d338340",
    "address": "Reign Street",
    "contactStatus": "Not Contacted",
    "contacted": [
      {
        "_id": "22435992",
        "date": "2022-12-27T04:58:47.306Z",
        "status": "Contacted"
      },
      {
        "_id": "22435992",
        "date": "2022-12-27T05:00:50.119Z",
        "status": "Contacted"
      },
      {
        "_id": "4f950467",
        "date": "2022-12-27T09:33:51.783Z",
        "status": "Contacted"
      },
      {
        "_id": "4f950467",
        "date": "2022-12-27T09:33:55.472Z",
        "status": "Contacted"
      },
      {
        "_id": "4f950467",
        "date": "2022-12-27T09:33:58.846Z",
        "status": "Contacted"
      }
    ],
    "fullName": "Jean"
  }
]
```

I've been trying this to add the new fields but it return "Not Contacted" to all of the data

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      contactStatus: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$contacted",
          initialValue: "$_id",
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this._id",
                  "$$value"
                ]
              },
              "$$this.status",
              "Not Contacted"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

this is my latest try, it only give true false as value but since there is more than 2 state in status I don't think this method is correct

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "contactStatus": {
        "$in": [
          "$_id",
          "$contacted._id"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
])
```

I'm not sure about using reduce but I couldn't think of any other way to check the userId from contacted array, please help me

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of choosing `$reduce` is a sensible one. You can set the `initialValue` to **Not Contacted** and update the value to **Contacted** only if both criteria are met. (i.e. _id matched and status is Contacted)

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      contactStatus: {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$contacted",
          "initialValue": "Not Contacted",
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$_id",
                      "$$this._id"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this.status",
                      "Contacted"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              "then": "Contacted",
              "else": "$$value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YercnMmkjzN)